# Changing Elements From A Referrer

Tags: jquery

I am looking for my website to update (not using classes just searching the body) and update selected elements (images, phone numbers, etc) when they come from a referrer.

I have the code to get it working using a class to change a number only.

```
lastUrl = document.referrer;

if(lastUrl.search("website") == -1) {
    $( ".snumber" ).each(function() {
        $(this).html("0418 888 666");
    });
}
```

I now need this to work with multiple elements not just one.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: multiple elements updated?  by class?

Comment: No multiple elements to be updated WITHOUT the use of a class. The code above shows with a class = snumber. I want to use it without a defined class. Is this possible?

Comment: So, what have the elements you want to update got in common that differentiates them from other elements on the page?

Comment: Elements have in common that they are all phone numbers.